# Get background-position of a sprite sheet element with javascript

Tags: javascript, sprite, sprite-sheet

Can I do this with vanilla js?

```
let bgPos = $('#image1').css('backgroundPosition').split(" ");
```

I tried with no luck:

```
let bgPos = document.getElementById('image1').style.backgroundPosition;
```

Comment: Since jQuery is written in "vanilla js", the answer to your question is yes, yes you can.

Comment: `.css('backgroundPosition')` will return them as percentages, where `style.backgroundPosition` will return them as defined, e.g. `center left` (at least that's the behavior I'm seeing when comparing them). But I'm not clear on what exactly the "problem" is - is that what you're referring to?

Comment: `style.backgroundPosition` will return it as it's defined, not necessarily `top right`, it can also be `40px 50px` or `90% 10%`. See [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundposition.asp)

Comment: I experimented more. I am trying to get the position of the  sprite sheet of an img object. The position is set via a class in a case sheet on loading the page. if I set backgroundPosition via JavaScript it does report it as desired.